# Scangearmp2 not detecting scanner

Tags: scanner, ubuntu-mate

I have a Canon TS9120 scanner.

I had to do a complete UbuntuMate 18.04 reinstall and lost all customizations etc.

I installed all the proper drivers, but scangearmp2 can not detect my printer.

Can someone please help with this as I use the scanner frequently.

Comment: With your reputation points I dare not answer.  BUT I suggest installing the sane-stable ppa. Then update sane.  Add sane-backends as well.  Then install gscan2pdf.  Try that.  ALSO install the printer the normal way once.  That may bring in with it the necessary connections/dependencies..

Comment: How do I install the sane-stable ppa? Then how do I update sane? @walttheboss

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git

Comment: What is "install the printer the normal way once" @walttheboss

Comment: Go to system settings and add printer.  Follow through the dialog.

Comment: Thanks walttheboss, my scanner is now working. :-)